# Can I use identical NSStrings as one sempahore for @synchronized

Tags: ios, nsstring, semaphore

As far as I know, identical NSStrings are optimized in such a way that they are actually one and the same object in most(all?) circumstances.

If yes, does that mean that I can use an NSString pointer as a semaphore for the @synchronized directive and have it block whenever the code block is being executed with an identical string as semaphore?

```
- (void)doSomethingWithAString:(NSString *)myString
{
    @synchronized(myString) {
        //Something time intensive that never happens in parallel for the exact same myString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, literal `NSString` instances with the same string are no longer guaranteed to be the same instance at the same address. This is a change that was made some time ago.

You can use a global string:

In file.h

```
extern NSString *const MY_SYNC_STRING;
```

In file.m

```
NSString *MY_SYNC_STRING = @"MYSyncString";
```

In otherFile.m

```
#import "file.h"
    ...
    @synchronized(MY_SYNC_STRING) {
    ...
```

Comment: OK. Any other idea how I could implement a string content dependent lock?

Comment: OK thanks. The global string doesn't really solve the problem, though.

Comment: You can add a method that caches string objects in a dictionary with the string name as the key. The you'd call @synchronized( [myClass getSharedObject:myString]) . Of course, you'd need to synchronize adding objects to that shared dictionary of strings with a global lock.